# Shared Query that refreshes other Queries in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a handful of Power BI Queries that hit the same datasource (Azure Blob Storage). Currently, when I want to refresh data, all the queries download the files from blob storage and parse them, making the process take far longer. Is there a way to have a query that does the download of the file and store it for other queries to read from so I don't have to download the same files over and over?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a blank query and reference the original query:
[image]

[image]

Then, when you refresh, the data in both queries will be downloaded only once.